# Metrization of the cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Can you help me please with this question?

Let $X$ be a non-empty set with the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology).

Is $\left ( X,\tau_{\operatorname{cofinite}} \right ) $ a metrizable space?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- If $X$ is finite, the cofinite topology is the discrete one, which is metrizable, for example using the distance $d$ defined by $d(x,y):=\begin{cases}0&\mbox{ if }x=y,\\
  1&\mbox{ otherwise}
  .\end{cases}$
- If $X$ is infinite, it's not a Hausdorff space. Indeed, let $x,y\in X$, and assume that $U$ and $V$ are two disjoint open subsets of $X$ containing respectively $x$ and $y$, then $U=X\setminus F_1$ and $V=X\setminus F_2$ where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are finite. Hence $\emptyset =X\cap F_1^c\cap F_2^c=X\setminus (F_1\cup F_2)^c$, which is a contradiction since $X$ is infinite. But each singleton is closed in such a space.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer above you could also say that for $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\in \cal{T}_{cofinite} \Rightarrow$ $X \backslash A=$finite $\stackrel{|X|=\infty}{\Rightarrow} A=$infinite (*). Then as the answer above states, for $(X,\cal{T}_{cofinite})$=metrizable its equivalent to say that $ \exists \; U ,V\subseteq X$ such that $U ,V \in \cal{T}_{cofinite}:$ $x\in U,$ $y\in V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$. For  $U ,V \in \cal{T}_{cofinite}$ $\stackrel{|X|=\infty}{\Rightarrow} 
 U,V=$infinite. And for $U ,V\subseteq X$ with $U\cap V=\emptyset \Rightarrow U\subseteq X \backslash V$ with $V \in \cal{T}_{cofinite} \Rightarrow$ $X \backslash V=$finite so we conclude that $U\subseteq X \backslash V=$finite which is a contradiction from the fact that we found that $U,V=$infinite.

(*) we know that because if $X=$infinite and $X \backslash A=$finite we exclude so many items from A in order to result to a finite complement, therefore we should had excluded infinite items from $A$ which contains them, thereafter cardinality of $A$ is infinite.

PS: I don't imply that for $A\subseteq X:\;X,A=$infinite then $X \backslash A=$finite (it could also be $X \backslash A=$infinite, and its unclear). But for $A\subseteq X,\; X=$infinite and $X \backslash A=$finite then $A=$infinite.